# How find all possible lengths of AD Quadrilateral ABCD?

Tags: geometry

Quadrilateral ABCD has AB = BC = CD = 12.  AC and BD intersect at P and AP, BP, CP, DP, and AD are of integral length. How find all possible lengths of AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this problem numerically. Take any possible value for $PB$ and $PC$ in $\{1,2,\dots,24\}$. For every choice of $PB$ and $PC$ you are able to find the coordinates of all points and see if the distances $AP$, $PD$ and $AD$ turn out to be close to an integer.